# How to simulate upstream with Nginx for dynamic subdomains

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-location

I would proxy a request like the upstream solution.

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$;
root /dev/null;

location / {
  error_page 502 @nextserver;
  resolver 127.0.0.1:53 valid=300s;
  proxy_pass "https://$subdomain";
}

location @nextserver {
  error_page 502 @error;
  resolver 127.0.0.1:53 valid=300s;
  proxy_pass "https://$subdomain-blahblah";
}

location @error {
    return 502 'Service is not available';
}
```

As you can see I would check `https://$subdomain` and if it doesn't exist or it down then checks `https://$subdomain-blahblah`.

it works fine but the problem happen when the second server is down, then Nginx doesn't provide `Service is not available` message.

So the scenario is like

```
   check Server A -> down
   check Server B -> down
   Return custom error
```

I couldn't use **upstream** because the name of servers is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to solve this problem differently. Check out this sample. It shows how you can approach the problem:

```
http{

    listen 80;
    root /path/to/static/files;

    upstream_server subdomain1{
        server 192.168.1.100:8000;
        server 192.168.1.101:8000;
    }

    upstream_server subdomain2{
        server 192.168.1.102:8000;
        server 192.168.1.103:8000;
    }

    location / {
      server_name subdomain1.example.com;
      proxy_pass http://subdomain1;
      include /etc/nginx/proxy_pass;
    }

    location / {
      server_name subdomain2.example.com;
      proxy_pass http://subdomain2;
      include /etc/nginx/proxy_pass;
    }

}
```

Comment: As I said, I can not use upstream because the subdomains are dynamic. I don't know what they are or when they generated or what's the name.

Comment: Ok. In that case I will suggest you to rename this question with something like "How to set generic suddomain with nginx".

Comment: Good suggestion, will do :)